# UK visa: "Are your partner or children applying with you?". Yes or No if my partner will only join later?

Tags: united-kingdom, visa, dependent-visa

I am currently applying for a UK visa.
My partner is planning to join me in future as a *dependant*, but is not going to apply right now (probably not this year).

On the online application form there is the section "People applying with you", the first question of which is "Are your partner or children applying with you?".

> **Question:** Should I answer Yes or No?

It would help to know what the exact purpose of this qustion is.

My partner is not applying with me *right now*. But is this question supposed to mean "right now", or more like "at some point"? Are there consequences for my partner if I select No?

Also, if I choose Yes, they ask for my partner's passport number, which we cannot provide, since we are just extending her passport and this will take some more time. What should I do in this case?

Answer (score 2):

If your partner is not included and not seeking a dependent visa in this application, then the answer is "No."

When your partner files later for a dependent visa, a separate, new application will be filed.

Comment: Thank you! What I do not understand: what would be the advantages of including my partner in this application if he/she has to write an own application anyways?

Comment: @M.Rumpy You're welcome. This is a different question, and we do one question at a time here. You can take the [Tour](https://expatriates.stackexchange.com/tour) to learn more about how this Stack works. In any event, please use the "Ask Question" button at the top right to ask a new question.

Comment: Thank you for the link. I am familiar with the SE system. Anyway, I would argue that this is not a new question: my post explicitly asks about the purpose of this specific visa application question, and giving advantages/disadvantages of answering in such or such way would provide an answer here. Your answer is very helpful, but I have to trust you on this. It would be much more helpful if it could be backed up with some source or rationale on why the procedure is in this way. Because if it appears implausible to me, then I am not sure that I am doing the right thing. I hope you understand.

Comment: Your question stated that your partner would not be applying with you, and asked if the "applying with you" question should be answered "yes" or "no." The answer to your question is self-evident, and is "no." UKVI Guidance does not address every possible application permutation; sometimes one must decide based on the reasonable meaning of the words. In any event, your partner cannot apply now because the partner's passport is out for renewal. If you want to apply now, you must apply alone. Whether you _should_ apply now or later is a different issue.

Comment: @M.Rumpy I don’t think there are any ‘advantages’ as such of including your partner in this application, she either wants to join you as a dependent *now* (if which case you include her) or she doesn’t (in which case you don’t). My assumption is that the question is intended to tie up the two applications, if two are made. A similar question is asked when eg someone applies for a Visitor visa and a family member(s) will be travelling with them; the family member still has to complete their own application