# Mentioning my partner on my UK visa as applying with me, but then she never applies

Tags: united-kingdom, visa, uk-visa, dependent-visa

I am currently applying for a UK visa.
My partner is planning to join me in future as a *dependent* but this is not certain.

The online application form in the section "People applying with you" asks "Are your partner or children applying with you?". I would have named my partner at this point (with passport number and everything) which I hoped might speed up her application process in the future.

> **Question:** Are there any problems if I mention my partner in this section but she never applies (or only much later)? In particular,
>
> - is there a chance that this will delay my visa application process since they are waiting for  my partner to apply?
> - are there any fees (for my visa) connected to mentioning my partner or mentioning her but then she never applies?

If neither, is my hope justified that it is a good idea to mention her?

Comment: IMHO it seems logical to assume that giving your partner’s details in the section you refer to is very likely to delay a decision on your application while UKVI wait for hers. You’d be telling them you intend for her to join you, they will want to have all the information surrounding your application before making a decision. I don’t see how including her now would speed up anything if/when she applies in the future - you’ll presumably already have your visa and UKVI will tie up the two. OTOH, it *might* be a red flag if you answer *No* now and she applies almost immediately anyway

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You're overthinking this.

You should answer (completely and truthfully) the questions asked in the application, but you're not required to volunteer information about matters *not addressed* in the application.

This is essentially the same question [you previously asked](https://expatriates.stackexchange.com/questions/22264/uk-visa-are-your-partner-or-children-applying-with-you-yes-or-no-if-my-part). What might happen with your partner in the future is important to you, but isn't important to the visa examiner, who is charged with assessing your application **now**, not as the application might be with different content in the future. Offering information about matters that haven't and may not occur will only complicate things, distract the visa examiner, and provide no benefit to you.

Let it go.